# Exported function error message in bash 4.3 vs 4.4

Tags: bash

When an exported function is called via `bash -c foo prefix` in bash 4.3, the error message prefix is "prefix". However, for the same command in bash 4.4 the error message prefix becomes "environment". How can I change the following script to produce the error message prefix "prefix" in bash 4.3 and 4.4? I will favor a solution that doesn't involve if-then-else or case-esac and equivalent constructs.

```
#!/bin/bash
foo() { eval if; } # generate an error
export -f foo
echo $BASH_VERSION
bash -c foo prefix
```

Script output comparison:

bash 4.3:

```
# /tmp/x
4.3.42(1)-release
prefix: eval: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

bash 4.4:

```
# /tmp/x
4.4.18(1)-release
environment: eval: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

I'm also interested in knowing why this happened, why did the string "environment" substitute $0 as the error message prefix in bash 4.4?